# Can I transfer a Windows 7 license to another computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, license, legal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

I was thinking of buying Windows 7 Ultimate to be installed on an old computer. In due time, I will be giving this old computer away.

The question is:

- Will I have trouble transferring the Windows 7 Ultimate license to another PC?
- If yes, do I need to watch out for any issues?
- What exactly is Microsoft's stance/policies towards license transfers?
- How many times can I transfer before it becomes illegal?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are purchasing a "retail copy" from a shop, you should not have any problems transferring it to another computer.

If you do run into a problem activating (which occasionally does happen) simply calling the Microsoft activation line (number given during the activation wizard) will allow you to activate it with a special code that you type in.

Comment: I've done this a number of times with both Windows XP and Windows Vista. The first couple of times you transfer the license it's no problem; after that, you do need to call Microsoft, but they're more than willing to help.

Comment: As @kez said below; the activation line for your country can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/activation-centers.aspx

Answer (score 8):

You can activate your license 2 or 3 times, so you should not have any issues. Worst case you will need to phone Microsoft to get the unlock key, but it is a fairly painless process, and I know in the States you can now even SMS them your code and they will send you back an unlock code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a full retail license you will have no issues

Note however:

An OEM 'system builder' license must stay with the computer it is first installed on. (I believe it links with the motherboard).

For a upgrade license, my understanding is that, *if* it is installed over an existing OEM install, you can't transfer the 'full' license to another computer - only the 'upgrade' part. However this shouldn't be a problem if the 'underlying' OS was a full retail copy to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a retail box of Windows 7, you can install it up to 3 times. After 3 times, your Windows 7 dvd turns into a frisbee.

Comment: It doesn't say this anywhere on the box (not on mine at least) and I've installed it at least 5 times.

Comment: when you say '3 times' do you mean: 3 different installations concurrently; or do you mean: 3 different installs 'one-at-a-time'? the 1st may apply to some versions (though i can't think of any), the 2nd is just plain wrong. -1

Comment: 3 times, I mean one-at-a-time! You cannot have at the same time 3 computers using the same single license.