# Can I upgrade from Windows 7 32bit to 64bit without formatting?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, upgrade

My friend installed Windows 7 on his computer (upgrading from XP).

He wasn't sure if his processor supported x64 or not, so he installed the x86 version, just to be on the safe side.

After I looked it up, it turns out his processor *does* support x64, and now we want to upgrade.

The question is: **is it possible to upgrade without completely re-installing the OS?**

Can I? Or do I have to format the C: partition again?

Comment: @Hennes: A shame I can't vote to close. Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. x86/32-bit to x64/64 bit is not supported in any version of Windows.

See also: [Upgrade from Windows 7 32 bit to 64 bit](https://superuser.com/questions/230316/upgrade-from-windows-7-32-bit-to-64-bit)

Tip for your friend:

1. Almost any CPU sold in the last decade is 64 bit capable.
2. You can look it up on the web, but briefly
   If it is an AMD it will be 64bit capable (those have been that way for ages).
   If it is an Intel check on http://ark.intel.com/
3. He could just have tried the 64 bit version of Windows 7. Worst case it would fail during the installation.

Comment: You probably meant `x64` on your third clause. Thanks. +1+v.

Comment: Yes, I did. Will correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The 64 bit operating systems has different folders that go different places and make sure everything runs properly. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can by booting up with a live CD/DVD and then erasing the entire windows directory only. Remove the hidden appdata/application data directory too. Program files may as well go too.

Startup from win7 64 bit disc and just install to C. Don't format.

I would only ever install windows this way if I didn't have any external drives to backup to.