# reinstalling windows 8.1 with only os partition format?

Tags: windows-8.1

when I reinstall windows 8.1 if I Don't format other partition because of the data. will there be a problem?
I have already formatted once without formatting any partition but windows. old is not able to delete

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I upgrade from Windows 7 32-bit to Windows 7 64 bit without reinstalling all of my software?](http://superuser.com/questions/75767/can-i-upgrade-from-windows-7-32-bit-to-windows-7-64-bit-without-reinstalling-all)

Answer (score 1):

You can format only the OS partition and perform a fresh install of Windows 8.1 without doing any harm to your other partitions. However if your computer was virused it is highly recommended to format all the partitions and perform a virus-scan after you install your operating system.

Comment: will there be a problem if I perform install without formatting any drive? because I already did that

Comment: It is not recommended to have multiple operating systems on the same partition. What is the reason for reinstalling your operating system?

Comment: 32 bit to 64 bit

Comment: have you done this before

Comment: Check this post: http://superuser.com/questions/553443/can-i-upgrade-from-windows-7-32bit-to-64bit-without-formatting

Comment: have you done it before formatting only os partition

Comment: yes. you have the option to format certain partition when you install Windows.

Answer (score -1):

When you will install windows there are two options one would be of upgrade windows and second onw would custom installation

Then choose custom one and select your windows drive ,If you dont want to save data of your windows drive say NO to prompt dialog which is saying do want to store old windows files .

Comment: so I don't have to format other drives

Comment: ofcourse not.. are you sure about earlier os that it was windows because problem occurs if it was linux ,unix or Mac

Comment: yes I  am sure that it is windows

Comment: then you can do it without any worries